# Javascript setInterval not working?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, webservice-client

I am working on a bit of code in Javascript that polls a time consuming process that is running in a webservice and returns the status every two seconds. The processPoll function is never getting hit and I can not figure out why the setInterval does not work. I think I have the scope right so I'm not sure why processPoll does not start.

```
   var processId;
   var timerId;

   function processStartReturn(retVal) {
       if ((retVal != null) && (retVal != "")) {
            processId = retVal;
            timerId = setInterval(processPoll, 2000);
            alert(processId); --> alerts correct Id
       }
   }

   function processPoll() { 
       alert("This alert never shows up!");
       WebService.MyFunction(processId, 0);
   }

   function startPoll() {
       var appName = document.getElementById("appName").value;
       var threadId = appName + "object";
       processStartReturn(threadId);
   }
```

Edit: I have added the startPoll() function that is started with an onclientclick event.

Comment: Try putting an `alert` or `console.log` call in the `processPoll` function, to see if it's firing every 2 seconds like you expect.

Comment: How do you know that the function isn't being called? Have you tried putting a `console.log()` call in there?

Comment: What piece of code is calling processStartReturn ?

Comment: make sure `retVal` equals what you expect

Comment: There is nothing incorrect. Show more code.

Comment: May be it's never getting inside `if`. May be there is no value in `retVal `. Try alerting `retVal` inside function

Comment: @Ani the posted code notes that the alert is called correctly

Comment: So I just ran `setInterval(function(){console.log('func called');}, 500); alert('foo');` in Chrome's JS console, and the function passed to `setInterval` isn't called until after I close the `alert` window. Calling `alert` again pauses the execution of the interval function again until you close the `alert` window. @kevlar90 Are you seeing `processPoll` execute after you close your `alert`, or does it not get called at all even after closing the `alert`?

Comment: Okay. Code is right - Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Anee/FwbB3/

Comment: ProcessPoll is not getting called at all even after I close alerts. Whenever I use console.log instead of alerts they appear on the console for a few seconds but then disappear.